# FindFailed: /Users/sgantayat/Documents/Screenshots/Sikuli/Login.png: (756x124) in R[0,0 1680x1050]@S(0)

Tags: selenium, sikuli

Getting below error while running the sikuli code in macbook pro
Calling login method!!!
Login screen display
Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}) on port 43572
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Apr 05, 2022 1:19:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FindFailed: /Users/sgantayat/Documents/Screenshots/Sikuli/Login.png: (756x124) in R[0,0 1680x1050]@S(0)
Line 2215, in file Region.java

```
at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2215)
at sikuli.sikulitest.loginToApp(sikulitest.java:58)
at sikuli.sikulitest.main(sikulitest.java:101)
```

Successsfully browser closed

here is my code

```
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        Pattern username = new Pattern("/Users/sgantayat/Documents/Screenshots/Sikuli/email.png");
        Pattern password = new Pattern("/Users/sgantayat/Documents/Screenshots/Sikuli/pwd.png");
        Pattern loginbtn = new Pattern("/Users/sgantayat/Documents/Screenshots/Sikuli/Login.png");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // dt.driverlunch();
        driver.get(appUrl);
        
        
        screen.wait(loginbtn, 10);
        // Calling 'type' method to enter username in the email field using 'screen' object
        screen.type(username, "softwaretestingmaterial@gmail.com");
        // Calling the same 'type' method and passing text in the password field
        screen.type(password, "softwaretestingmaterial");
        // This will click on login button
        screen.click(loginbtn);
        screen.wait(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

> screen.click(loginbtn);

did not work. It was not found on the screen.

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: then what should i use instead?